# I am having a problem using intellisense for my custom headers file in for c++ in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I tried compiling my shopping program with IntelliSense in vs code but is not working. Both the program and the header file are in the same folder called Shopping_program but that folder is in another folder called c++ which is where my .vcode folder is.

shopping_program.cpp

```
#include "shopping.h"
int main(){
    do{
        clear();
        choice();
        calculateTotal();
        receipt();
    } while(again());
    cout << "Thanks for shopping";
   
    
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          
          {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
              {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
              }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
          }
        ]
      
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{

    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Shopping_program/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
          "type": "cppbuild",
          "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
          "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
          "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",],
          "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
          },
          "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
          "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
          },
          "detail": "compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
        }
      ],
      "version": "2.0.0"
```

```
shopping.h
#ifndef SHOPPING
#define SHOPPING
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

const std::array <std::string, 3> products = {"Bread","Egg","Jam"}; //the product in the shop
const std::array <float, 3>  price = {10.0,5.50,7.20}; //the prices for the items

void clear();
void receipt();
void calculateTotal();
void choice();
bool again();
#endif
```

Comment: When you build your application you build with `${file}` and *only* `${file}`. That's the file currently being active in the editor. You need to list all your source files when building. Or better yet learn about build systems like `make` or more project-based build tools like CMake or Meson.

Comment: Are you getting linker errors or are you talking about red underlines in the IDE

Comment: If you do have an Intellisense problem can you show a picture of the problem.